# Download URL authentication in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

When a user clicks a downloadUrl supplied by an authenticated file list (via an access token), she doesn't need to send an access token again to download the file.

How does Google Drive know that this user has permission without supplying said token? Is it somehow encrypted within the downloadUrl?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the token, Use the `webContentLink` URL instead, then, if the user is logged in to their Google Account, the cookie will be used for authorization.

Comment: I'm happy to supply the token, but I don't seem to need it. I can copy and paste the downloadUrl into a new tab (without token) and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that, using a downloadUrl in a browser with no Authorization header is a 401 for me.

Comment: I just mean a new tab in a browser session that I'm currently logged-in and authenticated with. Does it fall back to authenticate using my cookies or something if I don't supply the access token.

Comment: Hi Ali, sorry to bug! I've made a little video highlighting my issue. Hope it helps - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjPwkx9938E

Comment: Sorry, after checking it seems I was wrong. It is not a supported feature though, which might vanish at any time.